# Is there a way to inherit a position:absolute div's height of a child without the parent being position:relative?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way I can make a parent div inherit the height of the `position:absolute` child it has without having to make the parent a `position:relative`?

Comment: A `position: absolute` child will never affect its parent

Comment: Even if you make the parent `position:relative` it won't assume the height of the absolute child. It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Paulie_D You are right, I was thinking about display table, my bad. But is there any way I could get a parent to get the height of a position absolute child?

Comment: Nope...that's the point. Absolute elements are out of the flow so don't contribute to parent height. If this is an actual requirement you need JS.

Comment: Slightly off topic, but I had to read your question three times before I realised that you shouldn't have used the word "inherit" there. Properties are not inherited upwards.